# Where could I stay for a single night stopover in Singapore to visit the botanical gardens?

Tags: accommodation, singapore, family

I arrive with my family in Singapore at 3pm one day and fly out 1pm the next.

Where would make sense to stay overnight if our main goal is to see the Botanical Gardens?

Considerations I'm trying to balance is where things are relative to the airport, and how easy it is to get from one to the other in the limited time.

I've read that it is best to visit the Botanical Gardens in the morning, so I am imagining arriving, finding hotel and dinner/sleep then get up early and go see Gardens then head to airport.

So - close to Gardens seems to make sense.    There appear to be a bunch of hotels around Cuscaden Rd.   So I'm wondering if this is the right place to choose, and whether any of these are notably good or bad?

Comment: Your question is attracting close votes as off-topic. I think it's because you asked somewhat indirectly for particular hotel recommendations. If you edit out the last part of the final question, it might be considered on-topic.

Comment: Just for reference, the train from the airport to Botanical Gardens takes around 52 minutes.